# Date difference using DAYS with DB2 issue

Tags: sql, date, db2

I have pasted this SELECT from a collegue which work on their table.   The table fields are exactly the same definition.  I used the same synthax and I keep getting a -180, ERROR:  THE DATE, TIME, OR TIMESTAMP VALUE *N IS INVALID

Here is my SELECT.  It is exactly as my colleague's and even similar to one in another answered question.   What causes this -180 issue?   I know it's a date format but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
SELECT                                                      
 CHAR(ID_T9999),                     CHAR('|'),             
 CHAR(IDENT_USER),                  CHAR('|'),             
 CHAR(DAT_START_CALC_PHYS),   CHAR('|'),                   
 CHAR(DAT_END_CALC_PHYS),     CHAR('|'),                   
 CHAR(LENGTH_PHYS)                               
 FROM T9999
 WHERE                                                        
 DAYS(                                                      
 SUBSTR(DAT_END_CALC_PHYS,1,4)||'-'||                      
 SUBSTR(DAT_END_CALC_PHYS,5,2)||'-'||                      
 SUBSTR(DAT_END_CALC_PHYS,7,2))   -                        
 DAYS(                                                      
 SUBSTR(DAT_START_CALC_PHYS,1,4)||'-'||                    
 SUBSTR(DAT_START_CALC_PHYS,5,2)||'-'||                    
 SUBSTR(DAT_START_CALC_PHYS,7,2)) > 10 ;
```

EDIT: TABLE.  Second and last columns in select don't matter.

| Id_t9999 | DAT_START_... | DAT_END.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 20080101 | 20080201 |
| 222222 | 20091010 | 20091015 |
| 333333 | 20120325 | 20120326 |
| 444444 | 20130710 | 20130721 |
| 555555 | 20140125 | 20140214 |

Result should be ID 111111,444444 and 555555 since their difference is more than 10 days.

Column for dates are declared integer.  Format is yyyymmdd.

Comment: so you have qa table we don't know nothing about wioth data about we also don't nothing about, and how should we help withput that information

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I added a table and date formats in input.  DAYS function require that the date be on yyyy-mm-dd format.  Hence the dashes

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/BDMyR-FR) statement as is as well?

Comment: that is an excellent idea but it is not allowed on Z/OS

Comment: Problem has been solved.  Columns are declared not null but contained dates at zeroes.  Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Sovled, thank you
Problem has been solved. Columns are declared not null but contained dates at zeroes. Thank you all